# Unable to configure Parse Server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-platform, mailgun

I have been trying to add S3 Adapter and Mailgun on my "AWS Bitnami Parse Server" unsuccessfully for like the last 4 days. This is how my server.js file looks at the moment:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database

// and the location to your Parse cloud code
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "",
    cloud: "",
    appId: "",
    masterKey: "",
    fileKey: "",
    serverURL: "",

    //FILES ADAPTER
    filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
             "",
             "",
             "",
             {directAccess: true}
    ),

    //MAILGUN
    verifyUserEmails: true,
    publicServerURL: '',
    appName: 'Parse App',   
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
                // The address that your emails come from
                fromAddress: '',
                // Your domain from mailgun.com
                domain: '.mailgun.org',
                // Your API key from mailgun.com
                apiKey: ''
            }
    }

});
```

All my keys and tokens are in place and double checked. 
I am not sure if this is an issue of missing a comma or something else, am I supposed to somehow reload the parse server after adding stuff on server.js ?

About the S3 Adapter, nothing is shown on the logs, it is as if that code isn't there and nothing is getting saved. Also should mention that the only reason I am trying to enable it is because nothing is getting saved on the default Grid Adapter. I think that might be because I am using the free option t2 micro but not sure. I keep getting "Unsupported URL" over and over when trying to download files on my iOS app.

When I try to reset a password, I get the following on the logs:

> Error handling request: { Error: An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality.
>       at UsersRouter._throwOnBadEmailConfig (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/UsersRouter.js:288:15)
>       at UsersRouter.handleResetRequest (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/UsersRouter.js:296:10)
>       at route.req (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/UsersRouter.js:397:19)
>       at /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/PromiseRouter.js:175:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>     message:
>      'An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality.',
>     code: 1 }

Hopefully someone can help me out. There isn't a lot of information other than written tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was having kind of similar errors 
After doing npm simple-mailgun-adapter
and after adding code to srver.js sometimes an instance reboot might be required to apply changes

on instance command line

```
sudo reboot
```

and hopefully it will work as it did for me.